# Extract a dictionary out of a list<T> using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, list, dictionary, group-by

I have list of `Pencil` objects `List<Pencil> pencils` as below:

```
public class Pencil
{
    public Pencil(int quantity, Color color)
    {
        Quantity = quantity;
        Color = color;
    }

    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

var pencils = new List<Pencil>
{
    new Pencil(3, Blue),
    new Pencil(2, Red),
    new Pencil(5, Blue),
};
```

What I want to do is to be able to extract a dictionary like this using **LINQ**:

```
Dictionary<Color, int> ColorAndQuantities;
```

Comment: OK, you want something, but what have you tried to get it? Or is it just like *"I am too lazy to read docs, do it for me"* type of question?

Comment: If you can't do it with linq, you can use classical loops to do it, can't you? Show your effort....

Comment: @Eser Why so angry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should group by color, and then using `ToDictionary` to create a dictionary that contains each color as the key and the sum of quantity for that color as the value like this:

```
var result =
    pencils
    .GroupBy(x => x.Color)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.Quantity));
```